# How do I properly handle the colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have long struggled with matplotlib understanding when to use fig/ax/plt after reading the documentation. Right now, I'd like to just give a title to the colorbar, but I always get stuck knowing which objects to store everything in and which to use later.

Could I get a general explanation to avoid going down such a path? Is there a more proper way I should be passing heatmap into ax so I don't run into this trouble again?

```
activity = 'Downstairs'
layer = 1

seg_x = create_segments_and_labels(df[df['ActivityEncoded']==mapping[activity]],TIME_PERIODS,STEP_DISTANCE,LABEL)[0]
get_layer_output = K.function([model_m.layers[0].input],[model_m.layers[layer].output])
layer_output = get_layer_output([seg_x])[0]

try: 
    ax = sns.heatmap(layer_output[0].transpose())
except:
    ax = sns.heatmap(layer_output.transpose())


ax.set_xlabel('Kernels',fontsize=30)
ax.set_yticks(range(0,len(layer_output[0][0])+1,10))
ax.set_yticklabels(range(0,len(layer_output[0][0])+1,10))
ax.set_xticks(range(0,len(layer_output[0])+1,5))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(0,len(layer_output[0])+1,5))
ax.set_ylabel('Filters',fontsize=30)
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 10
ax.set_title('Filters vs. Kernels\n (Layer=' + model_m.layers[layer].name + ')(Activity=' + activity + ')',fontsize=35)

#I'd like to add text to the colorbar but I don't know how to get it here. Fig/plt/ax.colorbar() don't work

clb = fig.colorbar()
```

Error:
colorbar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mappable'

Comment: There seem to be different problems here. The error is due to no argument given to `fig.colorbar`.  This should be the `QuadMesh` object created (but not returned) by heatmap. For this you need to dig in the axes children, `ax.collections[0]`. However, usually you get a colorbar for a seaborn heatmap by default. You can use `cbar=True, cbar_kws={...}` supplying any arguments to the colorbar.